# React "The node to be removed is not a child of this node" After dismissing Bootstrap Alerts

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to make my code simpler by creating a general React component for Bootstrap alerts. My current code is here:

```js
export function combineClassNames(...classNames) {
    return classNames.filter(c => c).join(' ');
}

export default function BootstrapAlert(props) {
    const newProps = {
        ...props,
        className: combineClassNames(props.className, "alert", `alert-${props.type}`, props.allowDismiss ? "alert-dismissible fade show" : null),
        role: "alert"
    };
    // Delete props will be handled by us, not passed to the <img> tag
    delete newProps.type;
    delete newProps.allowDismiss;
    
    return (
        <div {...newProps}>
            {props.children}
            {
                props.allowDismiss ? (
                    <button className="btn-close" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                ) : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works perfectly well if the user does not use the dismiss option. If they do use the dismiss option, it works at first, but as soon as they navigate away from the current page there is an error "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

I believe this is because the dismiss action on Bootstrap removes the entire element from the DOM, causing an error at a later point when that element is expected. Is there a way I can configure this behavior to simply hide the element or configure React to handle this case?

Comment: You can leverage React's state to conditionally render the component based on whether it should be visible or hidden. Instead of removing the element from the DOM, the component simply stops rendering when it is not visible and this should prevent the error you were encountering when navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by manually creating a transition that does not remove the element from the DOM instead of using Bootstrap, which does. This is based on the suggestion from Mile Mijatović. New code:

```js
export function combineClassNames(...classNames) {
    return classNames.filter(c => c).join(' ');
}

export function useMountEffect(callback) {
    useEffect(callback, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}

export default function BootstrapAlert(props) {
    const alert = useRef(null);
    const transitionDuration = props.transitionDuration || 200;
    const [shown, setShown] = useState(true);

    useMountEffect(() => {
          alert.current.style.transition = `visibility 0s linear ${transitionDuration}ms, opacity ${transitionDuration}ms linear`;
          alert.current.style.opacity = "1";
          alert.current.style.visibility = "visible";
    });

    function hide() {
        alert.current.style.opacity = "0";
        alert.current.style.visibility = "hidden";

        setTimeout(() => {
            setShown(false);
        }, transitionDuration);
    }

    const newProps = {
        ...props,
        className: combineClassNames(
            props.className,
            "alert", `alert-${props.type}`,
            props.allowDismiss ? "alert-dismissible fade show" : null,
            shown ? null : "d-none"
        ),
        role: "alert"
    };
    // Delete props will be handled by us, not passed to the <div> tag
    delete newProps.type;
    delete newProps.allowDismiss;
    delete newProps.transitionDuration;

    return (
        <div {...newProps} ref={alert}>
            {props.children}
            {
                props.allowDismiss ? (
                    <button className="btn-close" type="button" aria-label="Close" onClick={hide}></button>
                ) : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```